# Adding categories in wordpress from file

Tags: wordpress

I have list of categories and subcategories in file and I want to automatically add it to my wordpress page. Do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: See https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=wordpress%20import%20categories%20plugin

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-category/ it works